# Oracle pl/json to_clob() fails if json value is single character

Tags: json

we are trying to use PL/JSON package for our programs but it looks like that json.to_clob method has a bug. If you try this code:

```
-- json to clob bug in pl/json package
-- if json value is single character then that json value will not be shown in clob
declare 
  l_Data_json_clob   clob;  
  l_Data_json        json;
begin
  l_Data_json       := json(); 
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_Data_json_clob, true); -- create CLOB where result will be stored

  l_Data_json.put('RESULT', '1');--put one character in json value
  l_Data_json.to_clob(l_Data_json_clob);--put json result to clob
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr( l_Data_json_clob, 255, 1));--not correct json - json value is empty

  l_Data_json.put('RESULT', '22');--put two characters in json value
  l_Data_json.to_clob(l_Data_json_clob);--put json result to clob
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr( l_Data_json_clob, 255, 1));--correct json - more then one character

  l_Data_json.put('RESULT', 1);--put one number in json value
  l_Data_json.to_clob(l_Data_json_clob);--put json result to clob
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr( l_Data_json_clob, 255, 1));--again correct json but with number instead of string
end;
```

You will see that for some reason first json value is empty. We noticed that it is happening only if json value is single character. Is there any workaround for this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found that the bug is in JSON_PRINTER.ppString. The correct code should be:

```
procedure ppString(elem json_value, buf in out nocopy clob, buf_str in out nocopy varchar2) is
  offset number := 1;
  v_str varchar(5000 char);
  amount number := 5000; /*chunk size for use in escapeString. Maximum escaped unicode string size for chunk may be 6 one-byte chars * 5000 chunk size in multi-byte chars = 30000 1-byte chars. Maximum value may be 32767 1-byte chars */
begin
  add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, case when elem.num = 1 then '"' else '/**/' end);
  if(elem.extended_str is not null) then /*clob implementation*/
    while(offset <= dbms_lob.getlength(elem.extended_str)) loop
      dbms_lob.read(elem.extended_str, amount, offset, v_str);
      if(elem.num = 1) then
        add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, escapeString(v_str));
      else
        add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, v_str);
      end if;
      offset := offset + amount;
    end loop;
  else
    if(elem.num = 1) then
        while(offset**<=**length(elem.str)) loop
            v_str:=substr(elem.str, offset, amount);
            add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, escapeString(v_str));
            offset := offset + amount;
        end loop;
    else
        add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, elem.str);
    end if;
  end if;
  add_to_clob(buf, buf_str, case when elem.num = 1 then '"' else '/**/' end || newline_char);
end;
```